# Recursive function that returns combinations of size n chosen from list

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

I am trying to write a recursive function which takes as its inputs an integer `n`, and a list `l`, and returns a list of all the combinations of size n that can be chosen from the elements in `l`. I'm aware that I can just use itertools, but I want to become better at writing recursive functions, and I believe writing my own function will help me.

So for example, if you input:

> `n = 3`
>
> `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

I want the output to be:

> `[ [1, 2, 3],  [1, 3, 4],  [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4] ]

So far I've written this code:

```
def get_combinations(l, n): # returns the possible combinations of size n from a list of chars

    if len(l) == 0:
        return []

    elif n == 1:
        return [l[0]]

    newList = list()

    for i in range(len(l)):
    
        sliced_list = l[i:]
        m = n - 1

        #lost here, believe I need to make a recursive call somewhere with get_combinations(sliced_list, m)

    return newList
```

I found [this example of such a function for permutations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/) helpful, but I'm struggling to implement something similar.

To clarify, I set up my base cases in the way I did because I'm expecting to pass `sliced_list` and `m` in my recursive call, and if you imagine the situation when `i = 3`, you'll have an empty list for `sliced_list`, and `m` will be 1 when you've gone deep enough to build up a combination. But I'm not married to these base cases.

Let me try to summarize the questions I have:

1. How do I produce a final result which is exactly a list of lists, instead of a list of lists of lists of lists ... (depth = n)?
2. What should my recursive call look like?
3. Am I going about this problem in exactly the wrong way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: what about 1,2,4?

Comment: One approach: Look at the first item of the list. First handle the case that it is part of the combination -> remove it from list, decrease `n` and call recursively and prepend the item to the returned list items (which are lists, too); then case two, it isn't part of combination -> remove it from list but keep `n`, call recursively, join returned list to list from the first case. Appropriate checks for recursion termination are necessary, of course.

Comment: @Tacratis I have a math degree and somehow I missed that. Edited.

Comment: :) I only asked to make sure I understand your question correctly, but someone has already answered since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend that you layout your function like:

```
def get_combinations(array, n):
    solutions = []

    # all the code goes here

    return solutions
```

That way if there's a case that's a problem, like `n == 0`, you can just ignore it and get a valid (empty) result.  The next issue is this line is wrong:

```
elif n == 1:
    return [array[0]]
```

The correct thing to do if `n == 1` is to return an array with *every* element of the array wrapped in a `list`:

```
if n == 1:
    solutions = [[element] for element in array]
```

*This* is your base case as the next layer up in the recursion will build on this.  What comes next is the heart of the problem.  If `n > 1` and the array has content, then we need to loop over the indexes of the array.  For each we'll call ourself recursively on everything past the current index and `n - 1`:

```
sub_solutions = get_combinations(array[index + 1:], n - 1)
```

This returns *partial* solutions.  We need to stuff the element *at* the current index, ie. `array[index]`, onto the front of each `sub_solution` in `sub_solutions`, and add each augmented `sub_solution` to our list of `solutions` that we return at the end of the function:

```
solutions.append([array[index]] + sub_solution)
```

And that's it!

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly and I really appreciate it. I had actually gotten pretty close to the solution this morning, but it still wasn't quite right, and then your comment about making the base case a return of every element instead of just the first element clarified everything.

Comment: and the complete/updated code would look like what, for example? :-)